# Work with mocks in soap ui

Tags: soapui, soap-client

I created two same mocks as SOAP UI mock. I started these mocks, then i launched test, that linked to these mocks.
Unfortunately i saw that my test invoked only first mock. I didn't see that second mock is worked.
Is it possible to set some settings to decide this problem?

Comment: You need to show the details. How did you run two mock services? Any sample project to reproduce it for some one?

Comment: @Rao Here is the screen. I know exactly that only first mock working
[link](https://gyazo.com/2f20bac3d4a040b5e4f68c8dbfc844e3?token=73b89b11f80c949a5c1537ad8b9ed971)

Comment: What's your dispatcher to select the mock ? I think you need a condition to roam between your mocks [dispatcher](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/mockoperations-and-responses.html)

Comment: @Lerminou yep, it is interesting, i need something like that: i start my test first mock invoked, after that i fast launch test again (first test isn't finished yet) and second test invoked second mock.

Comment: @Lerminou  This dispatching doesn't work for several mock services

Comment: @BilowYuriy, you should be able to run the second mock service too in the same way. May be you can change the port number if there is any clash regarding the same.

Comment: @BilowYuriy, have you got chance to try as mentioned in the earlier comment?

Comment: @Rao I run two mock services, they are the same, they have same ports, same links except names.There is no clash in this case.I see that only first mock is working.When i stopped first mock, i see that second keep working

Comment: @BilowYuriy, ok. earlier screen shot is not clear. Can you screen with mock services on left side?